# netbook losing internet connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, internet-connection

I have a netbook that occassionally, usually once or twice a day, maybe more, will lose its internet connection while I am on Skype (that's when I notice it most, it may happen more often). The little yellow dot appears over the networking icon in the system tray, which when I click on it says no internet access at the top of the popup menu, and next to the router connection that I have.

Disconnecting and reconnecting usually rectifies full internet access again.

I'm not sure if leaving it for any amount of time allows the netbook to automatically reconnect again.

Everything seems fine with my laptop. I don't think this loses connection in the same way.

I'm using Windows 7 home premium.

Answer (score 0):

The "little yellow dot" might suggest that Windows cannot resolve the DNS address of microsoft.com which act as a Internet connection-test purpose).
If you are using DHCP to retrieve your adapter address, you should try to configure a static IP address for that adapter to see if the problem still exists, because DHCP has a fixed lease time.

What's more, you should also check your IP address when the "yellow dot" appears. Once your IP address is displayed as 169.254.x.x, it indicates that your DHCP fail to renew your IP address.